# choco install tidalcycles выдаёт ошибку связанную с установкой cabal

Tags: git, кодировка, windows-10, powershell, haskell

```
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
hosc-0.18.1-E8HvZE68mHq5JMr5fA0zfb depends on hosc-0.18.1 which failed to
install.
network-3.1.2.0-3J3aiSFSjtoHAHbAISoV5i failed during the configure step. The
exception was:
ExitFailure 1
random-1.2.0-34VvsK8CpZG1VOu2QdV8qX depends on random-1.2.0 which failed to
install.
splitmix-0.1.0.3-EyfRYyweSOi6qa3nGYeyF6 failed during the building phase. The
exception was:
ExitFailure 1
tidal-1.6.1-C6H7biwqkAh1U8sj1kXp7f depends on tidal-1.6.1 which failed to
install.
System.Management.Automation.RemoteException
```

Пробовала cabal update , cabal v1-update.
Подскажите что за ошибка и какимы могут быть пути решения.
Виндовс 10. Устанавливала по этому образцу https://tidalcycles.org/index.php/Windows_choco_install

Answer (score -1):

Нужно было прописать вручную пути в переменных средах

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]